# How to Concatenate values from combo box and a numerical field in access

Tags: ms-access, concatenation

I have created a form "Order" in which I want to concatenate values from the combo box "Order Series" (which be like R, Y, W, B, etc) and a numerical field "Number" (which be 1,2,3) of the form to a text box field " Order No" of the same box as R-1, R-2, R-3, Y-1, etc. I am using Microsoft Access 2007 with VBA.

```
Order Series     Number      Order No
R                1           R-1
R                2           R-2
R                10          R-10
R                11          R-11
Y                7           Y-7
Y                15          Y-15
W                10          Y-10
```

Comment: What language are you using ? What do you want to do ? Format a bit more your message, if possible.

Comment: You can add relating tag to your question. Ex: html, css, javascript...

Comment: I am using Microsoft Access 2007 with VBA

Answer (score 0):

You can set the *ControlSource* of the textbox [Order No] to:

```
=[Order Series] & "-" & [Number]
```